# How to prevent RF Kill disabling wifi

Tags: networking, wireless

I am facing a wireless issue with one of my machine in which it automatically went offline for some time. When I checked its status on the router page, it wasn't there. As it was not accessible using keyboard/mouse/hdmi, I had to restart it and after the restart, it came back online. I immediately checked the logs for any clue on why it went offline.

Here is the logs of `/var/log/daemon.log` of that particular time when the machine went offline.

`THIS IS THE TIME WHEN THE MACHINE WENT OFFLINE` **(May 21 08:38:00)**

```
May 21 08:38:00 Machine-04 dhcpcd[371]: eth0: removing interface
May 21 08:38:00 Machine-04 systemd[1]: Starting Load/Save RF Kill Switch Status...
May 21 08:38:00 Machine-04 avahi-daemon[332]: Interface wlan0.IPv6 no longer relevant for mDNS.
May 21 08:38:00 Machine-04 systemd[1]: Started Load/Save RF Kill Switch Status.
May 21 08:38:00 Machine-04 avahi-daemon[332]: Leaving mDNS multicast group on interface wlan0.IPv6 with address fe80::20d8:7961:155a:c338.
May 21 08:38:00 Machine-04 dhcpcd[371]: wlan0: carrier lost
May 21 08:38:00 Machine-04 avahi-daemon[332]: Interface wlan0.IPv4 no longer relevant for mDNS.
May 21 08:38:00 Machine-04 avahi-daemon[332]: Leaving mDNS multicast group on interface wlan0.IPv4 with address 10.1.140.6.
May 21 08:38:00 Machine-04 avahi-daemon[332]: Withdrawing address record for fe80::20d8:7961:155a:c338 on wlan0.
May 21 08:38:00 Machine-04 avahi-daemon[332]: Withdrawing address record for 10.1.140.6 on wlan0.
May 21 08:38:00 Machine-04 dhcpcd[371]: wlan0: deleting address fe80::20d8:7961:155a:c338
May 21 08:38:00 Machine-04 dhcpcd[371]: wlan0: deleting default route via 10.1.0.254
May 21 08:38:00 Machine-04 dhcpcd[371]: wlan0: deleting route to 10.1.0.0/16
May 21 08:38:00 Machine-04 dhcpcd[371]: wlan0: dhcp_envoption 119: Operation not supported
May 21 08:38:00 Machine-04 dhcpcd[371]: wlan0: dhcp_envoption 119: Operation not supported
May 21 08:38:00 Machine-04 dhcpcd[371]: wlan0: removing interface
May 21 08:38:00 Machine-04 dhcpcd-run-hooks[6825]: wlan0: stopping wpa_supplicant
```

From the above logs, I thought this is something to do with `RF Kill`. I started searching about it found this good [link](http://www.geekmind.net/2011/01/linux-wifi-operation-not-possible-due.html) which says that `RF Kill` mainly sync hardware and software and sometime it fails, due to which that particular interface `(Wlan0 in my case)` is soft blocked. The post also suggest few ways of enabling it back but as the machine which I have will not have any monitor/keyboard, so I am looking for a solution so that I can resolve this issue.

Is it true that `RF Kill` can softblock wifi.? If yes, then how can we enable it back automatically.?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I had the problem same with wifi not working in Ubuntu 16.04 Server. More than that, I got the `rfkill command not found` message.

I added the following line to `/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf`:

```
blacklist wmi
```

Then I added the following lines to `/etc/network/interfaces`:

```
auto wlo1
iface wlo1 inet dhcp
    wpa-ssid SSID
    wpa-psk PASSWORD
```

Where `wlo1` is the name of my wifi interface and `SSID` is the wifi network name and `PASSWORD` is the wifi pass.

Comment: This did not work for me and rfkill still disabled my WiFi randomly after some time

Answer (score -1):

THIS IS NOT A REAL SOLUTION, just a workaround to a much deeper rfkill problem.

After trying all these solutions and others (blocklisting all modules, deleting the module from /lib/modules/, creating startup scripts to unblock, creating system service to unblock, adding `rfkill.default_state=2` boot parameter, etc), rfkill was STILL automatically and randomly blocking WiFi. The only way I've been able to reliably resolve this is with:

`echo "*  *    * * *   root    rfkill unblock all" >> /etc/crontab`

This executes the `rfkill unblock all` command every minute to forcefully re-enable WiFi after whatever kills it. This does not prevent the random network interrupts, but at least it will reconnect after at most a minute.